# Sitecore Controller Rendering DataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rendering, sitecore

I have a component in Sitecore that can be used in the middle section of the page. It shows a video and is setup as a controller rendering in Sitecore. I have been able to get this to work by setting the DataSource on the rendering on the page item.

I have another component for the middle section of the page. This is a list of videos. Each video output has the exact same HTML as the rendering mentioned in the previous paragraph. I'm trying to call the controller rendering (mentioned above) in the rendering for this list rendering something like this -

```
@Html.Sitecore().Controller("VideoController", "Display")
```

I'm trying to set the DataSource in/before calling the .Controller function but I haven't found a way to do it. I'm looking for some answers on how to set the DataSource or call a controller rendering from another rendering.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be possible by statically binding the rendering and then adding the datasource as a parameter:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<your rendering definition item id>", new { DataSource = "<your datasource item id>" })
```

Comment: Do you have a way to set a data source on a controller rendering?

Comment: @Gabbar the `<your rendering definition item id>` should point to the definition item of your controller rendering. Sitecore does then automatically call your controller rendering.

Comment: You are right. I was passing in the path of the cshtml file instead of rendering id. When I passed the controller rendering it worked as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to use a datasource without configuring an Sitecore rendering?

Comment: @JackJackson sorry I don't understand what you mean. The datasource is a concept of Sitecore renderings, so how do you want to use this without a rendering?

Comment: @Kevin: That pretty much covers it, I suppose. I had wanted to move 9 lines of code and didn't want to create and deploy Sitecore items for that.