# Passing parameters to a Razor View rendering in Sitecore

Tags: .net, razor, sitecore, brightcove

I'm trying to render out the brightcove media player right now while passing a dynamic video id. The brightcoveData.Id is a valid guid but I can't seem to get the parameters passing properly so that the Rendering understands it. I get an error from this component saying "Media item are not selected."

```
var embedMedia = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            embedMedia.Add("playerId", "E7766078969C3AB892DD158E0E7230B9");
            embedMedia.Add("width", "400");
            embedMedia.Add("height", "300");

            @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Media Framework/Embed Media", new
                               {
                                   DataSource = brightcoveData.Id,
                                   Parameters = embedMedia
                               })
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the HTML output of the rendering? Does it look right?

Comment: also try stripping off curly braces {} from video guid.

Comment: Yeah the HTML output of the rendering looks right. Looks like i'm passing the DS wrong

Comment: @xoail - Removing curly braces didn't do anything

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597940/sitecore-controller-rendering-datasource try passing the rendering from sitecore instead with datasource param.

Comment: Yeah @xoail that's part of what I'm basing my work after. I removed the Parameters and didn't seem to matter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, after talking to Sitecore Support I got an answer:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Media Framework/Embed Media", new
                               {
                                   DataSource = brightcoveData.Id,
                                   Parameters = "playerid=E7766078969C3AB892DD158E0E7230B9&height=300&width=400"
                               })
```

brightcoveData.Id is just a guid string = "{XXXX-...-etc}". playerid is the Sitecore item id for the player you're using.

That's what the final code looks like and it works great! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can overwrite default properties with those parameters.

Sitecore will parse those parameters and add them as a `KeyValuePair<string, object>` object. You can access this object via `Rendering.Parameters`.

If you wan't to set up your own **Datasource** and Parameters you would have to use the **presentation details** in Sitecore and set the **Datasource** there.

Comment: I disagree http://ctor.io/specify-datasource-item-of-a-statically-binded-rendering/

Comment: @xoail I looked inside the SitecoreHelper class and this is what it does: `EnumerableExtensions.Each<KeyValuePair<string, object>>((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) TypeHelper.GetProperties(parameters), (Action<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) (pair => rendering.Properties[pair.Key] = ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault<object, string>(pair.Value, (Func<object, string>) (o => o.ToString()))));`
Seems to me that it adds the parameters as properties to the rendering. I can't find anything that overwrites existing properties.

Comment: As a work around I might be able to add the Embed Media (with an existing DS I could modify) to a placeholder and only show it as a conditional. I might try this approach... giving Sitecore Support like 1-2 more days to have an answer